# Lagrange dual problem when minimizing $x^3$ is infeasible

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the problem: minimize $ x^3$ subject to $x^2 \le 0, x \in \Bbb R$

I want to show the Lagrange Dual Problem is infeasible (i.e. $d^* = -\infty$)

We have $ L (x, \lambda) = x^3 + \lambda x^2 $

Then $g(\lambda) = \inf(L(x,\lambda)) = \inf( x^3 + \lambda x^2)$

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3 + \lambda x^2) = 0 \Leftrightarrow 3x^2 + 2 \lambda x =0 \Leftrightarrow x = \{ 0, -\frac23 \lambda \}$

Hence, plugging in the values we found into $g$ and varying $x$ we have that $g(\lambda) = - \infty $ if $\lambda =0$ and $g(\lambda) = \frac{4 \lambda ^3}{27} $ if $\lambda >0$

The dual is then: $ \max g(\lambda)$ subject to $\lambda \ge 0$

So the problem is infeasible because when $\lambda = 0 $ we have  $d^* = -\infty $ and so constraint cannot be attained

Is this approach correct?

Comment: $x^2 \leq 0$? You're taking $x$ to be complex or simply zero?

Comment: x is just simply zero, just a really weird way of putting it. I added the domain for clarification purposes.